# casting the generic class

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am passing an object into the function which takes it as a generic class.

```
public void insertToDB(T t) {
        String tableName = DynamoDBMapperConfig.DefaultTableNameResolver.INSTANCE.getTableName(t.getClass(), mapperConfig);
        itemValues = addData(tableName, t.getClass());
    }
```

Now, I checked that t.getClass() is returning the correct class. I am trying to add the data into my DynamoDB which has the following declaration.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "table")
public class SomeClass {
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
    public String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="createTime")
    public Date createTime;
    public void setCreateTime(Date createTime){
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }
}
```

the addData() which takes the tableName and generic class definition is as follows: I am taking the generic class because this function is going to be called my multiple DynamoDB and hence I want to keep it generic. Based on the tableName I will call the specific function to add data.

```
private HashMap<String, AttributeValue> addData(String tableName, Class<?> tClass){
        if (tableName.equalsIgnoreCase("table"))
            itemValues = add(....?);
// Unable to find what to pass in add() so that it can be of type SomeClass with preset values which were set before the `insertToDB() `
        return itemValues;
    }

private HashMap<String, AttributeValue> add(SomeClass someClass){
        addMapStringEntry(itemValues, "id", someClass.id);
        addMapStringEntry(itemValues, "createTime", someClass.createTime.toString()); // converting to string
        return itemValues;
    }
```

my question is, What should I pass in `add()` so that the actual definition can take `somClass`. I tried passing `tClass` but even though it is giving the correct class name `someClass` it is complaining about Required type: `someClass` and provided is `Class <?>

Comment: Why not make addData accept a SomeClass?

Comment: @Bohemian I will have multiple classes calling the function and hence, I am trying to make it generic.

Comment: `itemValues` is not defined in your `addData` method; it is not clear from this code what you're trying to do. I suggest you edit this answer and elaborate some. Note that in general 'I want to turn this T into a Class instance' has only answers that will disappoint you. There is no general 'just do this' that applies to all scenarios (In fact, usually, once you arrive at 'I wish to turn this T into a j.l.Class instance', that is merely you arriving at the dead end - the actual error in your design occurred much earlier).

Comment: @rzwitserloot my question is, What should I pass in `add()` so that the actual definition can take `somClass`. I tried passing `tClass` but even though it is giving the correct class name `someClass` it is complaining about Required type: `someClass` and provided is `Class <?>`

Comment: T represents a type, like `String`. A parameter such as `SomeClass someClass` accepts an instance of a type, like `"hello"`. These are completely different things. Thus, there isn't anything you can do, except perhaps invoke `tClass.newInstance()` and add generics cast - all code smells (i.e: Bad ideas, don't do these things). Instead take a step back, nobody says: "I know! I want to build an app that lets you cast a generics parameter!". What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish?